i want to set full screen like MobilityWare solitaire game in my application in android java
i'm trying below code for full screen but it's not hide status bar and if i try to remove status bar then not get full screen.
please give me proper solution for this.
please check --> MobilityWare - Simple Solitaire <-- game for full screen.
i want to set that type of full screen in android java
--> below code for full screen but showing status bar:
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS); getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN); getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS); getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
--> below code for hide status bar but it's not set full screen :
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
in the image status bar is visible i want to hide this and full screen both

When You post more code than single line use ``` instead of single `

Hello I'm using this and so far it was working but from what I can see this method is deprecated in API level 30
private fun setFullScreen(flag: Boolean) {
        val decorView = requireActivity().window.decorView
        val uiOptions: Int = if (flag) {
            (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        } else {
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        }
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = uiOptions
    }


please check --> MobilityWare - Simple Solitaire <-- game for full screen. (play store application)

Java version ( see
WindowInsetsController#hide(statusBars()) causes content to jump )
private void hideSystemUI() {
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);

WindowInsetsControllerCompat insetsController =   WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());
if (insetsController != null) {
    insetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
    insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars());
    insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars());
}

Kotlin version used in my app
    /**
 * This method is responsible to transfer MainActivity into fullscreen mode.
 */
@JvmStatic
fun setToFullScreen(window: Window) {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

    val insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
    insetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
    insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
}

part to be inserted in the onCreate method :
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)
    //
    if (supportActionBar != null) {
        supportActionBar!!.hide()
    }
    /*
    USED FOR FULL SCREEN
    */
    mywindow = getWindow()
    setToFullScreen(mywindow)


please check --> MobilityWare - Simple Solitaire game  || InShort App <-- (play store application) i want to that type of full screen

the code in my answer produces a full screen identical to that of Solitaire by MobilityWare installed from Google Play (I checked now). In my opinion you should try it

I tried your code but it doesn't work. I want a full screen in the app in which the space of both the status bar and navigation is covered, but the status bar and navigation are visible only when we swipe.
--> If you think so, you can also see the InShort app, not in the navigation, but in the status bar, that type is used.

In my app (naive AAC on Google Play) it works perfectly. But I have to apologize because in the answer I forgot to add the part to be inserted in the onCreate method (I added it now).  See also link

your code is working properly but i want to set full screen background with below flag :
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
and swipe to hide or show system bar, navigation and status bar.
